# install Add-ons on episerver cms

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, episerver

I have installed new episerver cms website and trying to install Add-ons “Episerver Forms” on my site using Nuget packages. I could not see the “Episerver Forms” from NuGet source. I have tried this by using the tutorial from the link https://world.episerver.com/documentation/developer-guides/CMS/add-ons/Installing-add-ons/. I had tried this by setting the installationMode as code in my webconfig file

```
<episerver.packaging installationMode="Code">
```

On the Nuget Source, I could not see the Add-ons "Episerver Forms".Can any one help me to install the Add-ons in to my wpiserver website?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add and use the Episerver nuget feed. `http://nuget.episerver.com/feed/packages.svc/`

Step 3 in the documentation.

```
3. Add http://nuget.episerver.com as a NuGet source.
```

Comment: Still I could not see the "Episerver Forms" after adding the NuGet source "http://nuget.episerver.com"

Comment: I have tried to install "Episerver Forms" using the command "PM> Install-Package EPiServer.Forms" on package manager console. I got following exception     "CommandNotFoundException"

Answer (score 0):

I have added the Nuget source "http://nuget.episerver.com/feed/packages.svc/" and then installed the Add-ons "EPiServer.Forms" using the Nuget package. I got this solution from the tutorial https://world.episerver.com/documentation/Items/Installation-Instructions/Installing-Episerver-updates/